# Syntax to concatenate two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to concatenate two fields of my Access 2007 database.

This is my query:

```
sql="SELECT CONCAT(COGNOME & ' ' & NOME) AS NOMECOMPLETO FROM clienti WHERE NOMECOMPLETO LIKE '%Rossi Paolo%'"
```

But it does not work, what is the syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

MS Access does not look like other SQL dialects.  This should be closer to what you want:

```
SELECT (COGNOME & " " & NOME) AS NOMECOMPLETO
FROM clienti
WHERE (COGNOME & " " & NOME) LIKE "*Rossi Paolo*";
```

Changes:

- There is no `CONCAT()`.
- `&` is used for string concatentation.
- Double quotes are used for strings.
- The wildcard for `LIKE` is `*`.

Comment: Access also doesn't recognize column aliases defined at the same level, so you'll either need to repeat the expression in the WHERE clause or use a subquery: `SELECT NOMECOMPLETO FROM (SELECT COGNOME & " " & NOME AS NOMECOMPLETO FROM clienti) WHERE NOMECOMPLETO LIKE "*Rossi Paolo*";`

Comment: It could be: `sql = "SELECT (COGNOME & " " & NOME) AS NOMECOMPLETO FROM clienti WHERE (COGNOME & " " & NOME)  LIKE '*Rossi Paolo*';"`.

Comment: @GordThompson . . . Good catch.  I didn't even notice that it was using the same alias.